# Using Random Seed to spawn Objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm working on a 2D mobile game in which you throw a spear at targets, which spawn outside of the screen and float from right to left on a set of fixed "rails" (Kinda like those shooting booths at the fair).  I'm wondering if it's possible / advisable to use a radom seed gerenator to set the speed and spawn location of the targets, instead of building every wave and level by hand. That way I could test them out and save the seeds that work well. So as to give every wave a more random feeling, without it being completely random and causing chaos. I'm quite new to this and I cant seem to find any relevant documentation on this. Any ideas?
PS. I wasnt sure whether or not my current target spawner script would be relevant here, if so just let me know and I'll edit it into this post. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds more like a general game design/game development question than a technical Unity specific question.

From a technical perspective: using random values to generate levels is very straightforward and will be quicker than designing levels/waves by hand.

From a game development perspective: generating random levels and then saving the ones you like is probably going to be slower and more difficult to manage than building the waves/levels by hand.  The key reason it's probably not going to work out well is because you will want to scale the difficulty of levels as player skill increases.  That means you will need to sequence your randomly generated levels/waves according to some criteria after you have created them.

From a game design perspective: letting random values completely generate your levels (even if you curate them) is probably a bad idea. Scaling game difficulty is an absolutely core part of a successful game engagement loop.  If a game becomes too difficult too quickly, players will stop playing.  If it is too easy for too long, players will stop playing.  If it plateaus or goes from hard to easy to hard with no apparent logic then players will stop playing. You want to be very hands on with scaling difficult by either: designing the levels by hand, or; designing and refining the algorithm that generates your levels.

That said, random values should be a part of your game if you want a degree of unpredictability.  But you want to MANAGE the effect of randomness to ensure it doesn't undermine gameplay.  For example, an easy level may have enemies that move at a random velocity between 1 and 10.  A hard level could have enemies that move at a random velocity between 30 and 60.  In other words, build your levels with constrained randomness.  Use the constraints to scale difficulty.

Thats just my two cents.

Comment: Yeah good point, I'll still look into whether or not that would be the correct approach to this.  Yeah the idea was to gradually increase difficulty by increasing the speed or changing the spawn locations. But I'll still mull it over. Thanks I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.Random` with a seed parameter to get the same values over and over again as long as you use the implementation in the same order and the same amount of steps.

```
var seed = 42;
var random = new System.Random(seed);
```

One problem that occurs is that you will not get the same values if you change your sources. If you find a nice seed for your level at one stage, this may be completely different later when you may have added new content (say a new type of spike).

So I would recommend that you use the seed while building your levels, then save the result of the level generation instead. If new content are added in later versions your previous levels will stay the same (hopefully). However if you would have generated the levels randomly at runtime using the seed you may get different results.

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    public static readonly int SEED = 42;

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Using {1,2,3,4,5}");

        int[] items = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5};

        for(var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
        {
            RandomFromSeed(items);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Using {1,2,3,4}");

        items = new int[] {1,2,3,4};

        for(var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
        {
            RandomFromSeed(items);
        }
    }

    public static void RandomFromSeed(int[] items)
    {
        Random random = new Random(SEED);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(items[random.Next(0, items.Length)]);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Using {1,2,3,4,5}
4113124314
4113124314
4113124314
4113124314
4113124314
4113124314
4113124314
4113124314
4113124314
4113124314
Using {1,2,3,4}
3113123314
3113123314
3113123314
3113123314
3113123314
3113123314
3113123314
3113123314
3113123314
3113123314
```

Comment: Ah I'll see if I can use this to implement it. Thank you.